# How to use the chrome.webRequest API in dart

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart

I would like to register a listener in `chrome.webRequest` API, like in the following JS example:

```
var initHttpRequestObserver = function () {
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
        function (details) {...},
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
}();
```

I guess I could use the `dart:js`, but wanted to use the `chrome` package and save some time/typing:

```
Stream<Map> aStream = chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders;
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to find out **how to supply the mandatory `filter` and `opt_extraInfoSpec` arguments**.

Answer (score 2):

After some analyses of the `chrome` package, it seems like it is not foreseen to invoke `addListener` with more then one parameter (a callback). The `common.dart` contains the private method where the actual invocation is being done:

```
void _ensureHandlerAdded() {
  if (!_handlerAdded) {
    // TODO: Workaround an issue where the event objects are not properly
    // proxied in M35 and after.
    var jsEvent = _api[_eventName];
    JsObject event = (jsEvent is JsObject ? jsEvent : new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(jsEvent));
    event.callMethod('addListener', [_listener]);
    _handlerAdded = true;
  }
}
```

Obviously `event.callMethod('addListener', [_listener]);` is not providing additional parameters.

The "official" `chrome` package requires a fix. In the meantime one can use the old good `dart:js` and do the following:

```
JsObject _OnBeforeSendHeaders = context['chrome']['webRequest']['onBeforeSendHeaders'];
var filter = new JsObject.jsify({"urls": ["<all_urls>"]});
var opt_extraInfoSpec = new JsObject.jsify(["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
_OnBeforeSendHeaders.callMethod('addListener', [_processCallback, filter, opt_extraInfoSpec]);
```